# Accordion expands all cards when clicked at any one

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

```
{% for inv in invoices__ %}
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                            <div class="card">
                                     <div class="card-header" id="{{inv.headingId}}">
                                            <div class="row headerContiner">
                                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                                   <h5 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{inv.collapseTarget}}">{{inv.ttl}}</h5> 
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-2">  
                                                    <a href="{% url 'invoice_update' inv.id__ %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-edit fa-lg"></i></a>      
                                                    <a href="{% url 'invoice_delete' inv.id__ %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                                                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg text-danger float-right"></i></a>     
                                                    <a href="{% url 'invoice_details' inv.id__ %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                                                    <i class="fas fa-file-invoice"></i></a> 
                                                    <a href="{% url 'invoice_status' inv.id__ %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                                                    <i class="fas fa-tasks"></i></a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>                                                                               
                                       </div>
                                       <div id="{{inv.collapseId}}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="{{inv.headingId}}" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                        <div class="row">     
                                                            {% for stg in inv.stages %} 
                                                                <div class="col-md-3 stags">                                                                  
                                                                        <h6 class="stepHeading">Step {{stg.counter__}}: {{stg.title}}</h6>
                                    
                                                                        <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the standard markup language for describing the structure of web pages. <a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                                                                        {% if stg.isCreated %}
                                                            
                                                                        <a href="{% url stg.editLink inv.id__ %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
                                                                            </a> 

                                                                        <a href="{% url stg.deleteLink inv.id__ %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                                                                            <i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg text-danger float-right"></i>
                                                                        </a> 

                                                                        <a href="{% url stg.previewLink inv.id__ %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                                                                                <i class="fas fa-file-invoice"></i>
                                                                        </a>

                                                                        {% else %}

                                                                        <a href="{% url stg.addLink %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                                                                            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                                                                        </a>
                                                                        {%endif%}
                                                                        
                                                                </div>
                                                               
                                                                
                                                         {% endfor %}
                                                        
                                                         </div>
                                                        
                                                </div>
                                                
                                         </div>
                                        
                            </div>
                            
                     </div>
             </div>
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I am trying to create an accordion I want only the currently clicked card to display and collapse other but here when I clicked at one card it expands all.

Code works perfectly fine other than this click. kindly help me ,thanks in advance

I am dynamically creating classes and id from the django view and transfering as part of context to template

I have not added any jquery or javascripts events to it.

Comment: What exactly does `invoices__` contain?

Comment: it contains list of different invoices about vendors ,only collapse and expand part is not working properly it expands all accordion cards when clicked at any card header. this is only issue I want only the clicked cards to expand rather all automatically expanded

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
            {% for inv in invoices__ %}
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="{{inv.headingId}}">
                    <div class="row headerContiner">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <h5 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{inv.collapseTarget}}">{{inv.ttl}}</h5> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">  
                            <a href="{% url 'invoice_update' inv.id__ %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
                            </a>      
                            <a href="{% url 'invoice_delete' inv.id__ %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                                <i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg text-danger float-right"></i>
                            </a>     
                            <a href="{% url 'invoice_details' inv.id__ %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                                <i class="fas fa-file-invoice"></i>
                            </a> 
                            <a href="{% url 'invoice_status' inv.id__ %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                                <i class="fas fa-tasks"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>                                                                               
                </div>
                <div id="{{inv.collapseId}}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="{{inv.headingId}}" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">     
                            {% for stg in inv.stages %} 
                            <div class="col-md-3 stags">                                                                  
                                <h6 class="stepHeading">Step {{stg.counter__}}: {{stg.title}}</h6>

                                <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the standard markup language for describing the structure of web pages. <a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                                {% if stg.isCreated %}

                                <a href="{% url stg.editLink inv.id__ %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                                    <i class="fa fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
                                </a> 

                                <a href="{% url stg.deleteLink inv.id__ %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg text-danger float-right"></i>
                                </a> 

                                <a href="{% url stg.previewLink inv.id__ %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                                    <i class="fas fa-file-invoice"></i>
                                </a>

                                {% else %}

                                <a href="{% url stg.addLink %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                                    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                                </a>
                            </a>
                            {%endif%}

                        </div>


                        {% endfor %}

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I move first 3 divs from inside loop to outside. In this way class accordion (and its ID) appears one time, not each loop.

Good luck!

bootstrap live example: see [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/collapse/#accordion-example)

Comment: No dear I was not assigning defferent class and id to each card , I fixed it thanks